# Why is the user parameter undefined in the discord.js 'messageReactionAdd' listener callback?

Tags: event-handling, discord.js

I've come across an issue while working on a discord bot and it's got me a bit stumped.
The client has a listener set up for the `messageReactionAdd` event, and the `user` parameter in its callback function is **always** `undefined` *unless* a message is sent while the bot is awake.

If a message was sent while the bot was awake, all reactions will fire the listener with a proper `user` value, **regardless** of when the message reacted to was sent. It's not feasible to just hope that a message is sent and cached by the bot before any reactions happen, so I need some help identifying what's going on here. This behavior doesn't seem to be related to the `message` event listener, as the problem is still present even if I delete that listener.

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    // user is undefined unless a message has been sent
    if(reaction.partial) {
        try {
            await reaction.fetch();
        }
        catch(error) {
            return console.error('Something went wrong when fetching the message: ', error);
        }
    }
    // do stuff here
}
```

I've also tried including a `await user.fetch();`, but it returns a 404 error since `user` has a value of undefined. Any insight would be appreciated, as I haven't been able to find documentation on this particular issue.

Comment: What is `reaction` in your case?

Comment: @FarrukhNormuradov `reaction` is a partial until the `reaction.fetch()` occurs, at which point it succeeds and it is replaced with a full MessageReaction object. The `reaction` parameter never fails to be initialized in the way that `user` does. Sorry, I should've clarified that as well.